# Facebook Passing Argument to JPG Files and Custom Image Display

Tags: php, html, facebook

I've noticed in **Facebook**'s source code, that images are links to a **PHP** file, `safe_image.php` (or `rsrc.php`; it changes every now and then), with the name of the selected file appended to the end, such as:

> https://external-lax3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?imagename1234

Or sometimes they're the usual **JPEG** files with a random token appended to the end:

> https://scontent-lax3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17353408_410522555967800_2778489440067836960_n.jpg?oh=3e00f84c6767364c9304b34f8751114d&oe=5954DA1E

What, I'm wondering is how they get a custom image viewer on their website. Usually, it's just a white background, with the selected image in the top left corner. However, they have it set in the middle with a grey-ish background.

Not only that, the linked image is direct back to the viewed **PHP** file; how is this possible, and how do they do it?

Cheers.

**EDIT**: I've also noticed if you change the `img` `src` to an invalid link, it will print an error to the page:

> The image " *Insert image link here* " cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Comment: What 'custom image viewer'?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware if you look at image source of other websites, you'll notice their images are shown on a white page, and the image is in the top left corner. When you go to one on Facebook, the image is central, and the background is a grey-ish sort of colour

Comment: I think you're discovering styles here. See: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I know how **CSS** works.. I've been a front end developer for 4 years. What I'm trying to figure out is how the did that specifically in the image view of a browser.

Comment: I see, so when you're directly accessing the image URL with your browser? It is a pity that you didn't provide a valid URL, I'll see if I can find one myself. Which browser do you use?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Ah, one moment, I'll try to find one. I use Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Well, yes, it is centered, and I'm using firefox. However, if I use an url of images in other sites, it looks exactly the same: centered.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware see edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Jpeg files, to no ones surprise, do not take in arguments.  However, PHP does.  So, what is most likely Facebook did is use a `rewrite` rule to 'map' their `.jpg?=` URL to a PHP file, which can process the arguments.  That PHP file then fetches the image data from a MYSQL (like) table.  If you're wondering, yes you can have the `.jpg` file extension display in the URL, load data from PHP, and have the image display properly in browser.

This can be achieved via `PHP` and `.htaccess`.

Firstly, let's setup our `.htaccess` inside whatever folder we want to have our `/img.jpg?=` inside of:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^img.jpg(.*)$ imageBackground.php$1 [NC]
```

Yay, now we are mapping our `img.jpg?image=bill` to `imageBackground.php?image=bill`.

And then we are going to write our `imageBackground.php`.  I wrote a very simple one, but basically all your doing is setting up headers (for which image format you're using) as well as display the image data.  Obviously in practical application this would be more complicated, like maybe you're dynamically grabbing image data from a database (like **Facebook**).

```
<?php

if ($_GET['image'] == "bill") {
    header("Content-type: image/pjpeg");
    echo file_get_contents("bill.jpg");
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll give it a shot in one moment! :D

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test it out yet. I've upvoted it for you though :)