# Replace questionsmark with slash

Tags: php, get, slash

I have a webpage where users can upload pictures, but there is a problem, I use get to know the name of the picture.

I use: `mypage.com/post.php?p=1`

But I want to use: `mypage.com/post/1`

Like in this website: http://m.nemkutya.com/like/117617

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Passing Argument to JPG Files and Custom Image Display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884830/facebook-passing-argument-to-jpg-files-and-custom-image-display)

Comment: Answer will depend on what platform you are running your webpage. Apache, nginx, IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you wish to provide your users access to their images with a slash-notation, rather than with URL query parameters? In such case you need to look in to pretty URLs.

One such example is `mod-rewrite` for Apache, and there's lots of good information around, such as:
 [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and “pretty links” explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)